# How to create a bitmap from a screenshot of a view bigger than the screen?

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I'm trying to create a bitmap that takes a "screenshot" of a view but who's bigger than the screen size, I need a bitmap of 1500px x 2115px to turn it into a pdf after that, but on phone is too big.

Here is my code which works if I use it with a tablet but not with the phone :

```
public void layoutToImage(View view, String imageName) {
    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    view.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(1500, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(2115, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));

    view.layout(0, 0, 1500, 2115);

    view.buildDrawingCache(false);

    Bitmap bm = view.getDrawingCache();
    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("image/jpeg");
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);

    File mFileImg = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + imageName);
    try {
        mFileImg.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(mFileImg);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Is this possible to achieve the same result on the tablet as on the phone? Any solution or suggestion will be helpful,
thank you.

Comment: Don't use the drawing cache. I know there are thousands of examples that show that, but it's never really been recommended. Use a `Bitmap.create()` method to create an appropriately sized `Bitmap`, create a `Canvas` on that `Bitmap`, then `view.draw()` to that `Canvas`. Be careful with big images, though, as it's really easy to run out of memory very quickly.

Comment: Thank you for advices !